# jQuery show/hide drop-down options based on another drop-down option

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-select

I am trying to create a drop-down select menu that will consist of three select boxes, where the 3rd box will show/hide specific option based on an option selected in the 1st select box.

I was wondering if anyone here is be able to suggest a solution to this.

Here is a simplified version of the 3 select boxes I have:

```
<select class="product" id="select_1" name="product">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Category </option>
  <option value="Mens Suits"> Mens Suits </option>
  <option value="Womens Suit"> Womens Suits </option>
  <option value="Children Suit"> Children Suits </option>
</select>

<select class="color" id="select_2" name="color">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Color </option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
</select>

<select class="size" id="select_3" name="size">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option>
  <!-- Mens Sizes Below -->
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="38">38</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <!-- Womens Sizes Below -->
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <!-- Children Sizes Below -->
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

With the example above, I would like to be able to view the first 3 options from the 3rd select box (`36`, `38`, and `40`) when the option `Mens Suits` from the 1st select box is chosen. Similarly, when the `Womens Suits` is selectedfrom the 1st box, the options `30`, `29`, and `28` should be visible in the 3rd box. The same with the Children Suits.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Can you say those conditions on which 3rd selection will show hide?

Comment: Try this solution [http://jsfiddle.net/mcSH5/](http://jsfiddle.net/mcSH5/)

Comment: @elena I updated my answer as per your conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var men = '<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option><option value="36">36</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="40">40</option>';
var women = '<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option><option value="30">30</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="28">28</option>';
var children = '<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option><option value="12">12</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="10">10</option>';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#select_1").on('change',function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Mens Suits"){
            $("select#select_3").html(men);
        }else if($(this).val()=="Womens Suit"){
            $("select#select_3").html(women);
        }else if($(this).val()=="Children Suit"){
            $("select#select_3").html(children);
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rTL9Y/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I tried in many different ways but this solution seems reasonable and I have used in my code. No plugins required simple register function with jquery object

Solution at glance:

```
(function ($) {


$('#showOne').click(function () {
    $('#ddlNumbers').showHideDropdownOptions('3', true);
});

$('#hideOne').click(function () {
    $('#ddlNumbers').showHideDropdownOptions('3', false);
});

 $.fn.showHideDropdownOptions = function(value, canShowOption) { 

         $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').map(function () {
            return $(this).parent('span').length === 0 ? this : null;
        }).wrap('<span>').hide();

        if (canShowOption) 
            $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').unwrap().show();
        else 
            $(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();

}



})(jQuery);
```

Here is the complete implementation http://jsfiddle.net/8uxD7/3/

Answer (score 1):

Updated the 3rd select

```
<select class="size" id="select_3" name="size">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option>
  <!-- Mens Sizes Below -->
  <option class="men" value="36">36</option>
  <option class="men" value="38">38</option>
  <option class="men" value="40">40</option>
  <!-- Womens Sizes Below -->
  <option class="women" value="30">30</option>
  <option class="women" value="29">29</option>
  <option class="women" value="28">28</option>
  <!-- Children Sizes Below -->
  <option class="children" value="12">12</option>
  <option class="children" value="11">11</option>
  <option class="children" value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

jquery code.

```
$("#select_1").change(function(){
     var selectedVal = $(this).val();

    if(selectedVal == "Mens Suits")
    {
     $(".women,.children").hide();
     $(".men").show();
    }
    else if(selectedVal == "Womens Suit")
    {
     $(".men,.children").hide();
     $(".women").show();
    }
    else
    {
     $(".women,.children").hide();
     $(".children").show();
    }
  });
```

Comment: @trainoasis try disabling the options $(".women,.children").attr("disabled","disabled");

Answer (score 1):

Use selectedIndex property to hide show third selection box

```
    $("#select_1").on('change',function(){
    if($("#select_1").prop("selectedIndex")==1){
        $('#select_3 option').show(); 
        $('#select_3 option:gt(3)').hide(); 
        //$('#select_3 option:lt(3)').show();
    }else if($("#select_1").prop("selectedIndex")==2){
     $('#select_3 option').show(); 
     $('#select_3 option:lt(4)').hide();   
     $('#select_3 option:gt(6)').hide();   
    }else if($("#select_1").prop("selectedIndex")==3){
     $('#select_3 option').show(); 
     $('#select_3 option:lt(7)').hide();   
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eezo/cWmXt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve that. From your example i can see that you only require 2 out of the 3 dropdown options to be filtering. Is this correct?

Please have a look **[HERE](http://www.dnasir.com/github/jquery-cascading-dropdown/demo.html)** as it will cover many more scenarios that just the one you are mentioning.

An example with 3 dropdown options that filter each other: **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4Zw3M/852/)**

```
Hope this helps
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html:

```
<select class="product" id="select_1" name="product">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Category </option>
  <option value="Mens Suits"> Mens Suits </option>
  <option value="Womens Suit"> Womens Suits </option>
  <option value="Children Suit"> Children Suits </option>
</select>

<select class="color" id="select_2" name="color">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Color </option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
</select>

<select class="size" id="select_3" name="size">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option>
  <!-- Mens Sizes Below -->
  <option value="Mens_36">36</option>
  <option value="Mens_38">38</option>
  <option value="Mens_40">40</option>
  <!-- Womens Sizes Below -->
  <option value="Womens_30">30</option>
  <option value="Womens_29">29</option>
  <option value="Womens_28">28</option>
  <!-- Children Sizes Below -->
  <option value="Children_12">12</option>
  <option value="Children_11">11</option>
  <option value="Children_10">10</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select_3").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
    $("#select_1").change(function() {
        $("#select_3").children('option').hide();
        $("#select_3").children("option[value^=" + $(this).val().split(" ")[0] + "]").show()
    })
})
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6GJA/)

Comment: This is a great example thank you! However, this will be a keywords search, so I need the values in all options to be as they were and not with a prefix in front.

Comment: Hi Greenhorm, this works perfectly in Chrome and firefox. but doesn't work in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css classes to distinguish the Sizes and show hide the options based on the category.

```
    <select class="product" id="select_1" name="product">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Choose Category </option>
        <option value="Mens Suits">Mens Suits </option>
        <option value="Womens Suit">Womens Suits </option>
        <option value="Children Suit">Children Suits </option>
    </select>
    <select class="color" id="select_2" name="color">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Choose Color </option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
    </select>
    <select class="size" id="select_3" name="size">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Choose Size </option>
        <!-- Mens Sizes Below -->
        <option value="36" class="men">36</option>
        <option value="38" class="men">38</option>
        <option value="40" class="men">40</option>
        <!-- Womens Sizes Below -->
        <option value="30" class ="women">30</option>
        <option value="29" class ="women">29</option>
        <option value="28" class ="women">28</option>
        <!-- Children Sizes Below -->
        <option value="12" class ="child">12</option>
        <option value="11" class ="child">11</option>
        <option value="10" class ="child">10</option>
    </select>
```

The above code having classes like "men", "women" and "child"` to distinguish the sizes.

Following script can be used to achieve the functionality.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select#select_1").on('change', function () {
               if ($(this).val() == "Mens Suits") {
               // Default show the Choose Size Option
                $('#select_3 option:first').attr('selected', 'selected'); 
                $(".men").show();
                $(".women").hide();
                $(".child").hide();
               } else if ($(this).val() == "Womens Suit") {
                $('#select_3 option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
                $(".women").show();
                $(".men").hide();
                $(".child").hide();
               } else if ($(this).val() == "Children Suit") {
                $('#select_3 option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
                $(".child").show();
                $(".women").hide();
                $(".men").hide();
               }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Hope this will help :)